Calling the function and processing the db.transaction are separated by a 4-minute delay
I am utilizing SQLite for a pre-made database, but I’m encountering an issue where querying even 70 rows of data can takes about 4 minutes.
Here is my code for querying the database:
export const getNouns = async query => {
var nouns = [];
var message = '';
console.log('Query home:' + new Date(), query);
await db.transaction(
tx => {
  console.log('Query home trans:' + new Date(), query);
  tx.executeSql(
    query,
    [],
    (tx, results) => {
      console.log('Query home result:' + new Date(), results);
      for (let i = 0; i < results.rows.length; ++i) {
        nouns.push(results.rows.item(i));
      }
      return nouns;
    },
    error => {
      console.log('error while executing the query: Execute: ', error);
      message = `error while executing the query: Execute: ${error}`;
    },
  );
},
error => {
  console.log('error while executing the query: Transaction:', error);
  message = `error while executing the query: Execute: ${error}`;
 },
);
return nouns;
};

here is how i call the function to get the data
const MainHome = () => {
var nouns = [];
useEffect(() => {
async function fetchData() {
nouns = await getNouns('SELECT Id, Text, User, CreatedAt FROM Messages');
 }
 fetchData();
});

console.log(Messages Home page: + new Date(), nouns);
return (
   <View style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
      Main Home Screen
  {nouns.map(item => {
  return (

  {item.User}

  );
 })}

  );
 };

here is the screenshot of the time taken to call the function and process it

